# String is treated differently when extracted from DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing a very weird problem with Javascript. When I extract text from DOM and try to decode HTML entities, it's not working. However, when I assign the value directly in the code, it's working just fine.

I just don't get why the string is treated differently in both cases. I have tested in FireFox and Chrome and both produce the same result.

**Update**:
The correct output should be %7B (after decoding the string). That means that when I assign the value directly to the variable it's working correctly, but when extracted from DOM, it's not. How can I extract the text from DOM and decode it so it produces "%7B" ?

**DEMO**: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h920nz3h/1/)

**HTML**:

```
<div class="myclass">\u00257B</div>
```

**Javascript Code:**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    //Extracting the text from DOM
   var myText = $(".myclass").html();
    //decoding HTML entities
   var decodedText = $("<div />").html(myText).text();
    //alerting the decoded text
    alert(decodedText); // output: \u00257B

    //assigning the value directly to the variable
   var myText2 = "\u00257B";
    //decoding HTML entities
   var decodedText2 = $("<div />").html(myText2).text();
    //alerting decoded text
    alert(decodedText2); // output: %7B

});
```

Comment: Did you end up finding a suitable solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `myText2` produces a different result is because the backslash in string literals is an escape character.

to escape a backslash, simply use it twice:

```
myText2 = "\\u00257b";
```

[Here is a some further information about escape characters in JavaScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/2yfce773(v=vs.94).aspx)

---

### EDIT

There's probably a better way, but this will work:  (eval is generally frowned upon and has security implications if the value from your text is uncontrolled input)

```
myText = eval("\"" + decodedText + "\"")
```

Comment: Thanks , I have tested it and it's working. However, I still don't get it. it's supposed to work the same way in both scenarios, right?

Comment: No, it's working as expected.   In a string literal in javascript a backslash is not an actual backslash.   If your reading an existing string though, the backslash is already the escaped value that represents a backslash.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because when you extract the string from the dom the "\u" is escaped.

If you do `var myText2 = "\\u00257B";` you'll get the same result

http://jsfiddle.net/9n6t5qxr/1/

if you do `console.log('\u0025')` it prints `%`, which is why you are seeing `%7B`